# SELECT query "greater than" not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function of code written on my site to display user messages:

```
function fetch_conversation_summery(){
    $sql = "SELECT
                `conversations`.`conversation_id`,
                `conversations`.`conversation_subject`,
                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`
                MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
            FROM `conversations`
            LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
            INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
            WHERE `conversations_members`.`userid` = {$_SESSION['userid']}
            AND `conversations_members`.`conversation_deleted` = 0
            GROUP BY `conversations`.`conversation_id`
            ORDER BY `conversation_last_reply` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $conversations = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
        $conversations[] = array(
            'id'               => $row['conversation_id'],
            'subject'          => $row['conversation_subject'],
            'last_reply'       => $row['conversation_last_reply'],  
            'unread_messages'  => ($row['conversation_unread'] == 1),
        );
    }

    return $conversations;
}
```

Although when I try and use this on the correct page, it issues an error :

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
```

I located the problem to be within the query, in the line:

```
MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
```

Although there seems to be nothing I can see wrong with it, all of the table names are correct and still it is giving an error? Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

P.S the code works fine without the MAX line where I mentioned the error was located.

Comment: What datatype is your `message_date` column?

Comment: The message_date is an INT of 10.

Comment: Try adding `echo mysql_error();` after you run the query. Also, have you tried to run the query against the database with phpmyadmin (or other app)?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I am getting : Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u634727706/public_html/core/functions/pmsettings.php on line 20

Comment: That is a php error, not a mysql error. If the query fails mysql_query will return a boolean value (false) and not a resource (which is a pointer to the result of the query). Adding `echo mysql_error();` after you run the query will show any mysql errrors.

Comment: Have you tried parentheses `(MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) > conversations_members.conversation_last_view) AS conversation_unread`

Comment: You are also missing a comma before that line.

Comment: Correct, there is a missing comma after `conversation_last_reply` in the select list.

Comment: Any reason to tag this question in html?

Comment: Do you have wintery conversations too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after this line:

```
MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`
```

should be:

```
MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`,
```

Answer (score 0):

try replace this

```
   MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
```

by

```
  CASE WHEN MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` THEN max(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) END AS `conversation_unread`
```